# Can I swear to a computer game??? Can I show myself through YouTube?

Tags: game

So I wanna start making videos online... Me playing games. I wanna know if it's all right if I can swear AT the game and AT non-existent-people(ai/npc) and not swear at real life people. The game you could think of as an inanimate object?? Also, I want to know if I can show myself through YouTube like putting in a facecam for my gameplays and stuff like that.

Comment: If the answers below satisfy your query please mark the relevant one as accepted. Else please elaborate on your doubts/questions.

Answer (score 2):

Islam does not differentiate between cursing on animate and non-animate objects. ***It is the act itself which is disliked.***

> Ibn Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) said, "A true believer does not taunt or curse or abuse or
>   talk indecently."
>
> [Riyad as-Salihin - Book 18, Hadith 224](https://www.sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/224)

And

> Abdullah narrated that the Messenger of Allah said: "The believer does
>   not insult the honor of others, nor curse, nor commit Fahishah, nor is
>   he foul."
>
> [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1977](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/83)

And

> Narrated `Abdullah bin`Amr:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said. "It is one of the greatest sins that a man
>   should curse his parents." It was asked (by the people), "O Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ)! How does a man curse his parents?" The Prophet (ﷺ)
>   said, "'The man abuses the father of another man and the latter abuses
>   the father of the former and abuses his mother."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 5973](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/78/4)

W.r.t showing your face on YouTube, it would depend. If you fear fitna due to your face being shown (maybe you are a handsome male or a beautiful female whose face distracts others in a wrong way and/or you fear you may gain arrogance due to the fame), then it is better to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Games, singing or listening to music, dancing and seeing willingly dance, art, drawing, sculpture are harsh in Quranic Islam, and I hope if you are a Muslim brother you will avoid it, it's all up to you and your choice.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We require answers here to be focused on answering the actual question, well elaborated and any claim to be supported by evidences (to post a great answer I suggest you to read [answer]).